# How to find the closest corresponding vectors between two coordinate matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, euclidean-distance

I have the following problem in Python I need to solve:

Given two coordinate matrices (NumPy ndarrays)  `A` and `B`, find for all coordinate vectors `a` in `A` the corresponding coordinate vectors `b` in `B`, such that the Euclidean distance `||a-b||` is minimized. The coordinate matrices `A` and `B` can have different number of coordinate vectors (that is, different number of rows).

This method should return a matrix of coordinate vectors `C` where the ith vector `c` in `C` is the vector from `B` that minimizes the Euclidean distance with the ith coordinate vector `a` in `A`.

For example, lets say

`A = np.array([[1,1], [3,4]])` and `B = np.array([[1,2], [3,6], [8,1]])`

The Euclidean distances between the vector `[1,1]` in `A` and the vectors in `B` are:

```
1, 5.385165, 7
```

So the first vector in `C` would be `[1,2]`

Similarly the distances for the vector `[3,4]` in `A` and the vectors in `B` are:

```
2.828427, 2, 5.830952
```

So the second and last vector in `C` would be `[3,6]`

So `C = [[1,2], [3,6]]`

How to code this efficiently in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `cdist` from [`scipy.spatial.distance`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) to efficiently get the euclidean distances and then use [`np.argmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) to get the indices corresponding to minimum values and use those to index into `B` for the final output. Here's the implementation  -

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

C = B[np.argmin(cdist(A,B),1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [99]: A
Out[99]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [3, 4]])

In [100]: B
Out[100]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 6],
       [8, 1]])

In [101]: B[np.argmin(cdist(A,B),1)]
Out[101]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 6]])
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! =) I'm doing computationally heavy calculations so that's why efficiency is important in my problem :)